# markov property of Brownian motions

Tags: brownian-motion, markov-process

In Schilling's "Brownian Motion" chapter 6, p60, I found the followin theorem:

> [image]

but I have several questions:

(1) Does "$\cdot$" in (6.3) mean "$\omega$" ? and we don't write it explicitly by convention? just like we write $\mathbb EX$ instead of  $\mathbb EX(\omega)$ ?

(2)I can't understand the proof of (6.5) because I can't figure out what $\Psi$ should be in (6.3). In (6.3) $\Psi$ has 2 arguments but in (6.5) $\Psi$ only has 1 argument.

Comment: No, it just mean it is a function dependent on $\omega$. If you insert a $\omega$. The mapping in 6.3 will return a real number. If you leave it out, it is a general mapping dependent on $\omega$. Originally $\Phi$ has two argument. But he makes in 6.3 the first argument also dependent on $omega$ by introducing the random variable X. Hence, the mapping in 6.3 depends only on $\omega$

Comment: @quallenjäger by "The mapping in 6.3 will return a real number", do you mean $\Psi$ will return a real number? but it *does* return a real number since $\Psi:\mathbb R^d\times \Omega\to \mathbb R$

Comment: And what you are saying is also right. I think in 6.5 he means $Psi(B_t(\omega),\omega)$. Since the expectation is integrated over all $\omega$, he leave it out. It is Basically same expression as 6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) In (6.3), $\Psi(X(\cdot),\cdot)$ is a name for the map $\omega\mapsto \Psi(X(\omega),\omega)$.

(2) Schilling and Partzsch make an awkward notational choice here. Let's instead use $\Phi$ in (6.5). Then $\Phi(B_{\cdot+s}(\omega))=\Phi(B_{\cdot+s}(\omega)-B_s(\omega)+B_s(\omega))=\Phi(W(\omega)+B_s(\omega))=\Psi(X(\omega),\omega)$, where $\Psi(x,\omega):=\Phi(W(\omega)+x)$, and the other ingredients are as in the last sentence of the proof.